# Gear Sport watch face ... native works but not web

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, watchface, wearables

I have a Gear Sport and I am trying to install my web (html + js) watch face, but the watch will not let me make it the default watch face. I try to add it and it tries for a few seconds and then goes back to the previous watch face.

This same watch face runs fine on my Gear S3 (Tizen 3.0.0.1).

So I tried the sample watch faces in Tizen Studio. The web apps also fail the same way as my watch face, but the native ones work just fine. For example, DigitalWatch (web) does not work but DigitalWatch (native) works fine. This is on Gear Sport.

On Gear S3, they both work fine.

Has anyone else seen this? I can't find any other forum posts and google searches found nothing. It seems that the sample web watch faces should work on Gear Sport.

I'm using Tizen Studio version 2.2.

Thanks!

Comment: As an update, I have also tried to run the sample Tizen watch face apps on the emulator (Tizen 3.0). Same as with Gear Sport, the native watch faces work but not the web based ones. It installs OK and initially runs, but will not let me set it to be the default watch face. It reverts immediately back to the previous one. Can anyone repeat  this? Thanks.